# Plug XBee into an Android device

Tags: android, xbee

If I connect an XBee device (e.g. XBee S2B) to an Android smartphone (as USB host) using a USB XBee adapter module, will I be able to communicate over the XBee network using serial communications from an Android app?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the xbee device and/or the manufacturer of the xbee adapter module.

Comment: Well I've tagged my question as xbee and android, so hopefully someone here will know or have experience of doing something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've managed to get hold of an old broken XBee, but it works well enough to indicate that it has power and has a flashing light when serial data is received. I plugged it into a galaxy s6, downloaded an Android app to create a serial connection and it looks like it does work. Power light is on, and the rx,tx lights flash as expected.